# Error when installing igraph for Python

Tags: python, macos, installation, igraph

I am trying to install igraph for Python by using the following command

```
brew install homebrew/science/igraph
```

I am using a macbook pro with OS X 10.10.2. I already update to the last version of Xcode. My current interpreter is Python 2.7.8 Anaconda. However, I am getting the following errors. Does anyone know how to deal a with them? Thank you.

```
==> Installing igraph from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Downloading http://igraph.org/nightly/get/c/igraph-0.7.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/igraph-0.7.1.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1
==> make install
ld: illegal text-relocation to '___gmp_binvert_limb_table' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from '___gmpn_divexact_1' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libigraph.la] Error 1

make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

After @Tamás suggestion the C core can be installed. However, when I tried to build and link to Python it complains. This is the result. Any suggestion?

```
Downloading/unpacking python-igraph
  Downloading python-igraph-0.7.1-4.tar.gz (375kB): 375kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/04/b6v_36_j6cg88_d_jnwpl26r0000gp/T/pip_build_user/python-igraph/setup.py) egg_info for package python-igraph

Installing collected packages: python-igraph
  Running setup.py install for python-igraph
    sh: line 1:  1261 Segmentation fault: 11  'gcc' --version 2> /dev/null > '/var/folders/04/b6v_36_j6cg88_d_jnwpl26r0000gp/T/tmpajZnqq'
    Build type: dynamic extension
    Include path: /usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/include/igraph
    Library path: /usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/lib
    Linked dynamic libraries: igraph
    Linked static libraries:
    Extra compiler options:
    Extra linker options:
    building 'igraph._igraph' extension
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/user/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/Users/user/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c src/arpackobject.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/arpackobject.o
    gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/user/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/04/b6v_36_j6cg88_d_jnwpl26r0000gp/T/pip_build_user/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/04/b6v_36_j6cg88_d_jnwpl26r0000gp/T/pip-r3zUzu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/clustering.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/configuration.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/cut.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/datatypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/formula.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/layout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/matching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/statistics.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/summary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

copying igraph/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/atlas.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/attributes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/basic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/bipartite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/cliques.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/colortests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/conversion.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/decomposition.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/edgeseq.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/flow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/foreign.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/games.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/generators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/homepage.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/isomorphism.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/iterators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/layouts.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/matching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/operators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/rng.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/separators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/spectral.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/structural.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

copying igraph/test/vertexseq.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/test

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

copying igraph/app/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

copying igraph/app/shell.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/app

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/baseclasses.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/colors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/coord.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/edge.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/metamagic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/shapes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/text.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

copying igraph/drawing/vertex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/drawing

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/gephi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

copying igraph/remote/nexus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/remote

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

copying igraph/vendor/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

copying igraph/vendor/texttable.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/igraph/vendor

running build_ext

sh: line 1:  1261 Segmentation fault: 11  'gcc' --version 2> /dev/null > '/var/folders/04/b6v_36_j6cg88_d_jnwpl26r0000gp/T/tmpajZnqq'

Build type: dynamic extension

Include path: /usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/include/igraph

Library path: /usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/lib

Linked dynamic libraries: igraph

Linked static libraries:

Extra compiler options:

Extra linker options:

building 'igraph._igraph' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/user/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/Users/user/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c src/arpackobject.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/arpackobject.o

gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory

gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: It could be the case that you have some non-Homebrew version of the `gmp` library hanging around on your system that confuses Homebrew. What does `brew doctor` tell you?

Comment: I included the the brew doctor diagnostic. I also forget to mention that the interpreter I am using is Python 2.7.8 Anaconda @Tamás

Comment: Is the `gmp` library on your system installed from Homebrew? Also, this bug report for `gmp` in Homebrew could be related: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/12946

Comment: @Tamás how can I verify if the `gmp` library is from Homebrew? Moreover, following the link you pointed out, how can I add the "--with-pic" configure option to my `gmp`? I mean what file do I need to modify and where? Thank you.

Comment: `brew info gmp` should tell you whether `gmp` is installed by Homebrew or not. (If it isn't, the output contains `Not installed` around line 3). To pass the `--with-pic` option, use `brew edit gmp` to edit the Homebrew formula for `gmp` and add `"--with-pic"` to the `args` variable - it's in line 21 in the formula I have on my machine for `gmp`.

Comment: Thank you @Tamás. I already could install the C core of igraph. However, we I tried to install the python link `pip install python-igraph` by typing `pip install python-igraph` it complains. I have updated the build result in the corpus of this question. Do you know why?

Comment: I can only see the result of `brew doctor` in the question.

Comment: @Tamás now it is updated in the question.

Comment: Something seems to be seriously wrong with the C compiler on your machine; it seems not to know the `-arch` option and it throws a segmentation fault. What does `gcc --version` print on the console?

Comment: @Tamás it prints `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: Then your C compiler is malfunctioning and you have to fix it (probably by reinstalling) before trying to compile `python-igraph`.

Comment: @Tamás I reinstalled my compiller and now it works. Thank you.